# How to upgrade outdated Drupal 7 version

Tags: 7, upgrading

I'm using Drupal 7.10 which is an outdated version. Is it safe to just upgrade to the latest version or should I upgrade version by version from 7.11 until the latest version 7.21?

Comment: If you have drush installed, you can simply do `drush up drupal` and your update is done! Don't forget to run the database updates after you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade directly to the new version as it contains all the previous changes as well. But don't forget to follow the backup instructions...

Answer (score 1):

just go to your command prompt , switch to your site folder and use the command "drush pm-update drupal"
this ll help you out ..:)
in an easy way..

happy coading :)

Comment: Thank you for the advise. The drush tool is helpful indeed.